# Group sorting JQuery list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I would like to sort list elements based on its group.

For example:

This:

- Apple - Fruit
- Banana - Fruit
- Sour Bomb - Sweets
- Grapes - Fruit
- Cranberry - Fruit
- Chocolate - Sweets

Will become:

- Apple - Fruit
- Banana - Fruit
- Cranberry - Fruit
- Grapes - Fruit
- Chocolate - Sweets
- Sour Bomb - Sweets

Alphabetically, the group items of Fruit is sorted first, then Sweets.

I am not too sure how to make it so that both sort is correct. For example, I tried sorting the groups then the food items but the group will not be sorted.

```
function sorting() {

function sortASC(a, b) {
    return $(b).find(".group").text() < $(a).find(".group").text();
}

$("li").sort(sortASC).appendTo('ul');

}
```

Comment: can you also post html along with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build it all into one sort function:

```
function sortASC(a, b) {
    // Cache Text
    var a_group = $(a).find(".group").text(),
        a_item = $(a).find(".item").text(),
        b_group = $(b).find(".group").text(),
        b_item = $(b).find(".item").text()

    return (
        b_group < a_group            // If group is bigger
        || (                         // OR
            b_group == a_group       // If groups are same
            && b_item < a_item       // AND item is bigger
        )
    );
}
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcqr02zc/4/)**

Comment: Hi Stryner, thanks for your answer. Can you clarify some bits for me please, as I'm still confused on how it works. How does the next part of the OR statement gets executed if the b_group < a_group is executed first? It will not sort the b_items right? How come it does?

Comment: @Newtonic Because of [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation). If `a_group` is larger than `b_group`, then whole expression returns true. Otherwise, it will evaluate the 2nd condition.

Comment: Sorry, think there's a misunderstanding. I meant if the first statement gets executed, then the items would not get sorted? Because the items is only sorted on the second statement.

Comment: @Newtonic The first statement sorts the groups since the groups are the most important sort. If one group is "larger" than the other, then it doesn't matter what the item is. Fruit will always be sorted above Sweets, regardless of if the fruit is "Grapes" and the sweets is "Chocolate". You only care about sorting the item names when the groups are the same.

Comment: "If one group is "larger" than the other, then it doesn't matter what the item is." How come? Wouldn't the items be unsorted? I understand the second statement that sorts the items if the group is the same. But the first one doesn't sort the items, after the group is sorted.

Comment: @Newtonic The sort function only compares [2 items at a time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) (items `a` and `b`). You can imagine it working like a [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: Thank you! Bubble sort cleared it up very well :) Thanks for being so supportive.